# I'm trying to do a simple math by removing one book copy from my library every time some one loan one

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the line that makes me all the trouble, My question is how can I remove one int(number) from books_library?

*example of my book_library:*

```
    {'Books': 
[{"Book's ID": {'003'},
 "Book's Name": {'Avengers'},
 "Book's Authors": {'Stan Lee, Jack Kirby'},
 "Book's Published year": {'1939'},
 "Book's Type": {'1'},
 "Book's Copies": {15}}
```

- 

```
books_library["Books"][book]["Book's Copies"][0] = books_library["Books"][book]["Book's Copies"][0] - 1
```

> Returns me an Error : TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable

```
 with open('loans_data.pkl', 'wb') as loans_save:
    for book in range(len(books_library["Books"])):
        if book_name_input in books_library["Books"][book]["Book's Name"]:
            books_library["Books"][book]["Book's Copies"][0] = books_library["Books"][book]["Book's Copies"][0] - 1
            book_details = {"ID":books_library["Books"][book]["Book's ID"],
                            "Name":books_library["Books"][book]["Book's Name"],
                            "Author":books_library["Books"][book]["Book's Author"]}
            for customer in range(len(customers_library["Customers"])):
                if customer_name_input in customers_library["Customers"][customer]["Customer's Name"]:
                    customer_details = {"Name": customers_library["Customers"][customer]["Customer's Name"],
                                        "ID": customers_library["Customers"][customer]["Customer's ID"]}
                    loan_library["Customer"].update({customer_details:{book_details}})
                    pickle.dump(loan_library, loans_save)
```

Comment: Print books_library["Books"], then books_library["Books"][book] to find the problem. We can't debug for you

Answer (score 1):

Due to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) `set` data structure is unordered collections of unique elements and that doesn't support operations like indexing or slicing etc.

```
>>> test_set = {1, 2, 3}
>>> test_set[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

In your case `books_library["Books"][book]["Book's Copies"]` is set, so you should change it to `list` or another type that you want (looks like it should be just integer).

Answer (score 0):

An important thing to learn is to pay attention to what exactly those errors say. They are intended to be helpful. Here, for example, it says

`TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable`

So what does subscriptable mean?
Simplified, to get an item from a sequence or dictionary, or a user defined object by using a key or index. This is taken straight from the python docs.
[See here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=subscriptable#grammar-token-python-grammar-subscription).
But it says *set* is not subscriptable. So you go and look up what exactly a set is in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set), and there you find out that its a builtin data structure that does not support subscription.
And you see that the syntax for creating a set is {itemlist}. So you have just used sets for all the values in you dictionary, with unintended side effects!
The solution is to not to use sets - storing different kinds of data in a dict works exactly as it would normally: {key: 1} stores and int(1), {key: [1,2]} a list and so on, so in your example you would use

`"Book's Copies": 15`

Conclusion: Listen to what python tries to tell you and use the docs, they are excellent.